# question about this if/else code using || and &&

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string vegetarian, vegan, gluten_free;
    cout << "Welcome to Restaurant Selector!" << endl;
    cout << "Are you a vegetarian?"<<endl;
    cin >> vegetarian;
    cout << "Are you a vegan?"<<endl;
    cin >> vegan;
    cout << "Are you gluten-free?"<<endl;
    cin >> gluten_free;

    if (gluten_free == "yes" && vegan == "yes" && vegetarian == "yes" )
    {
            cout<<"The Chef's Kitchen"<<endl;
    }
    else if (gluten_free == "yes" && vegan == "yes" )
    {
            cout<<"Vegan's lair"<<endl;
    }
    else if (gluten_free == "yes")
    {
            cout<<"Starbuck's"<<endl;
    }
    else if ( gluten_free == "no" || "No" && vegan == "no" || "No" && vegetarian == "no"||"No")
        cout<<"Burger King"<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the first if expression to use multiple variations of yes.
I want it to include: yes, Yes, and YES. however I can only use the or operator on two strings. I would also like to do this for the subsequent lines. What should I do?

Comment: You could use tolower(). That only does it for one character so you'd have to iterate the length of the string calling this function for each char ( str[i] = tolower(str[i]) ). This way your string will always be lower case and you can check it like you already are

Comment: keep in  mind, this never works the way you describe: `gluten_free == "no" || "No"`
The || operator always has a boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the first if expression to use multiple variations of yes. I want it to include: yes, Yes, and YES.

Convert the input string to lower case before comparison.

A trivial example:

```
auto tolower = [](unsigned char c){
    return std::tolower(c);
};
std::transform(
    vegan.begin(),
    vegan.end(),
    vegan.begin(),
    tolower
);
```

Note that simple string processing such as this work only with fixed width encodings and not with unicode.